# AngularJS & NodeJS - handle user roles

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, permissions, roles

Consider I have mini `User CRUD` application, frontend AngularJS and backend NodeJS/Express. App has register/login, `create/read/update/delete` functionalities for user. User can have two roles, `admin` or just `normal user`. Admin has permission to do all of CRUD operations, while user can only `read/update` - (and update only itself). 
What is best practice on backend, to handle user roles? And what on frontend, how to hide admin sections from normal user? 
What came on my mind is to add middleware that will intercept every request and check user roles/permissions for desired endpoints (C/U/D)....I will use bearer for Authentication...

Comment: This is a bit too broad of a question for SO because it is opinion based and there are several correct answers.  I like using JWT to authenticate API requests which you could also use to store permissions (Some people hate using JWT to store session data).

Comment: You can simply do it only with frontend. Once you have user info you can hide the features you don't want the user use.

Comment: And the auth detail in your token and handle the UI accordingly. create another table for AUTH section in which you will store the UserId and AuthId in this way many System works